# Deployed application at context path [/abc] but context failed to start - Maven Spring Project Issue

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a maven spring web-app which is deployed on AWS Beanstalk and working fine. Now, I want to shift it to OCI VPS/VM and use tomcat7-maven-plugin to deploy using the maven command. Using command line args to pass DB credentials. followed the below steps but deployment is failing.

1. Installed Maven and Tomcat 9.
2. Added a user in **tomcat-users.xml** with role **manager-script**

```
<user username="role-user<" password="role-pwd" roles="manager-script"/>
```

3. Added the plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.2</version>
     <configuration>
         <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
         <username>role-user</username>
         <password>role-pwd</password>
         <path>/abc</path>
         <update>true</update>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

4. Ran the command to deploy - `mvn -Ddb.user=db-user -Ddb.pwd=db-pwd tomcat7:deploy`

It uploads the WAR in /webapps then fails with this message `FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/abc] but context failed to start`.

I tried it on my local also, thinking maybe the setup on VM needs some additional config, didn't work.

In the logs, it says db.user property not found, so not able to read command line args for some reason.

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder
```

Before trying the above steps, I tried to upload the WAR file via the Tomcat UI and it didn't work because I don't know how to pass additional args there or if it is even possible.

If someone can help with either of those approaches it would be much appreciated.

TIA

PS - I am not a Java developer and this is a side project I work on sometimes, last time I used java/tomcat in a project was more than 7 yrs ago. So, maybe there is a silly mistake or straight forward solution and I am not aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn -Ddb.user=db-user -Ddb.pwd=db-pwd tomcat7:deploy
```

This command does not mean that war will be deployed in a tomcat VM with these system properties (db.user, db.pwd) The documentation is not good enough (https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/run-mojo-features.html) but look at the `systemProperties` section

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
 <configuration>
     <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
     <username>role-user</username>
     <password>role-pwd</password>
     <path>/abc</path>
     <update>true</update>
     <systemProperties>
       <db.user>${db.user}</db.user>
       <db.pwd>${db.pwd}</db.pwd>
    </systemProperties>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then run via mvn command:

```
mvn -Ddb.user=db-user -Ddb.pwd=db-pwd tomcat7:deploy
```

This should hopefully work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but didn't work. Added `systemProperties` tag, but still the same error

Comment: Ah! This works only with run goal. https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat6-maven-plugin/examples/add-system-properties.html

Comment: Ran `mvn -Ddb.user=db-user -Ddb.pwd=db-pwd tomcat7:deploy tomcat:run` getting Address already in use, JVM_BIND. Seems like Maven is starting another Tomcat instance which is conflicting with the already running one.

Comment: [INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/abc
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at C:\Users\abhay.yadav\Downloads\abc-project\target\tomcat
Aug 09, 2023 9:47:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
Aug 09, 2023 9:47:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work after some tweaks

Remove username,password and url from plugin details

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
 <configuration>
     <path>/abc</path>
     <update>true</update>
     <systemProperties>
       <db.user>${db.user}</db.user>
       <db.pwd>${db.pwd}</db.pwd>
    </systemProperties>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Use the below command to deploy
`mvn -Ddb.user=db-user -Ddb.pwd=db-pwd tomcat7:run`

It will start its own tomcat container, hence is no need to run any instance of tomcat beforehand or create any user in `tomcat-users.xml`

Once you see the below lines on terminal/cmd

```
Aug 10, 2023 11:49:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

App is deployed and can be checke on the browser at `localhost:8080/abc`

If need to change port(eg-8081) add `<port>8081</port>` under `configuration` tag

But now I am curious about how the previous thing works, have seen many posts/blogs about that. If anybody knows, please comment.